# Qt5 installation default host unreachable

Tags: 16.04, qt5, mirrors

I got a really annoying error when I want to install Qt5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
Network error while downloading 'http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/licenses/qt.license.gplv3except/1.0.0-1meta.7z' : Mirror host is unreachable.
```

But when I use `firefox` and go to this [address](http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/licenses/qt.license.gplv3except/), the mirror is here and the link is totally valid !

how is it possible that Qt5 installation software didn't find the mirror, when we can access it manually with a web browser like Firefox?

NB: I start the QT5 installation software by command line

```
./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.5-online.run
```

Comment: I'm sorry but why you do not want to use packages from official repositories? You will get [Qt 5.5.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=qt5). From my experience running `*.run` files may produce unplanned headache.

Comment: @N0rbert it's for installed a program named `yuview` which was used with Qt5.8 and Qt5.11, so Qt5.5.1 won't be enough

Comment: @ damadam. OK. Just wanted to inform you about APT-way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found two interesting moments about YUView:

1. YUView has FlatPak version. See their [wiki-page](https://github.com/IENT/YUView/wiki/YUView-on-Linux).
2. YUView compiles normally using stock Qt5 from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install qt5-default
   cd ~/Downloads
   git clone https://github.com/IENT/YUView.git
   cd YUView
   qmake
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

   and runs normally with `YUView`

   [image: YUView on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]

Comment: The Flatpak version is totally new (upload 22 hours ago)

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentations, I have found how to install completely Qt5; with the file `qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.5-online.run`, you must use `sudo` command, because it won't have access at all mirrors list, and print the error that you can see in the question :

```
sudo ./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.5-online.run
```

Qt5 would be installed a few time after downloading.

NB: At installation of Qt5, **don't** select ALL, that point will dissuade you : 75 GB of installation (all version 5 of Qt5 + some others package) which mean some download.

Comment: You should not run that Qt installer with sudo.